# как в powershell выкинуть с удаленного сервера всех, кроме указанных пользователей?

Tags: powershell

Собственно хочу выкинуть с терминального сервера всех пользователей, кроме тех, кого я укажу
Использую такой скрипт:

`$server   = 'MyServer'
$username = $env:USERNAME

$session = ((quser /server:$server | ? { $_ -match $username }) -split ' +')[2]

logoff $session /server:$server'`

Как в него добавить исключения по username, что бы не выкидывал указанных пользователей?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось таким скриптом,
делает LogOff для всех активных пользователей кроме выбранных:

```
   $Servers= "server"
   $Username1 = "user1"
   $Username2 = "user2" 
   foreach($Server in $Servers)
 {
    try {
        query user /server:$Server 2>&1 | select -skip 1 | ? {(($_ -split "\s+")[-7] -ne $Username1) -and (($_ -split "\s+")[-7] -ne $Username2)} | % {logoff ($_ -split "\s+")[-6] /server:$Server /V}
    }
    catch {}
    }
```